# When logging out of Firebase, data from user is persisted when next user logs in

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have an issue with a swift app that uses firebase.I have several observers set up that are watching firebase nodes and populating UITableView.

When I log out, then log in as a new user, the old user's data is still visible until I fully close the app and then restart it, at which point it populates with the current user's data. I expect that this is caused by a local cache of some type, as I am removing all observables on logout.

Has anyone experienced this before and have any ideas how to solve?

Comment: Remove all observers you created when you logout , second clear all array values that maybe used to show data in TableViews for safer side when user Logs out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove all observers when you do logout:

```
self.ref.child("child").removeAllObservers()
```

And also you need to clear your array value's :

```
if yourArray.count > 0{
   yourArray removeAllObjects()
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the tableviews data was being stored between changing the rootview of the window, but that's what it ended up being.